# How to edit the text string "Contact Form"

Tags: database

How to edit the text string "Contact Form". Client wants it to say Inquiries. People are using it to make booking which he would like to avoid.
Thanks.

http://chrisgarsidepodiatry.com.au/index.php/contact-us/mudgeeraba

Comment: @coolycafe  If your question is sufficiently resolved, please award the green tick to Neil's answer.  If you are not sure what I am talking about, read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the Contact component in Joomla 2.5.

If so, you may be able to create a language override to change the heading.

Go to Extensions -> Language Manager -> Overrides -> New and under "Search text you want to change", enter "Contact Form", set "Search for" to "Value" and click on the "Search" button.

Click on the appropriate search result which might be "COM_CONTACT_FIELDSET_CONTACT_FORM"  or similar. This will populate the 'Create a New Override" form for you. You can then change the "Contact Form" text to whatever you like and then click on "Save & Close" to save and close.

Refresh the Contact Page in your browser to check for changes.

If you have chosen the wrong language string, you can always delete the override you created and try again.

Comment: Hi Neil, Thanks that worked a treat. What a strange way to edit a text string though. I tried every other method that I thought was logical but simply couldn't find how to change it. Thanks again.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to edit the language file directly but the advantage of the recommended method is that the change will survive future Joomla updates.

Comment: OK, just for my own knowledge where would I find that. I am a total newbie to Joomla, didn't build this site, just inherited it.

Comment: It would be something like /language/en-GB/en-GB.com_contact.ini or similar.